# how to make group by column value should appear at only first row

Tags: sql, oracle

In oracle, query is resturning this dataset

```
DEPT | EMP_NAME | SALARY
-----+----------+-------
10   | MARY     | 30000
10   | JOHN     | 20000
10   | SCOTT    | 20000
20   | BOB      | 50000
20   | BETTY    | 50000
```

my objective is to make it as below

```
DEPT | EMP_NAME | SALARY
-----+----------+-------
10   | MARY     | 30000
     | JOHN     | 20000
     | SCOTT    | 20000
20   | BOB      | 50000
     | BETTY    | 50000
```

dep name should appear at once until new dep start.

Comment: doing that requires some sort of ordering. What makes "shoaib" the first row? It might not always be the first row returned, unless you've got one or more columns to order by.

Comment: This is something you shouldn't do in SQL, but in your GUI layer (app or Website) where you are displaying the data in some grid or table.

Comment: i have updated my question. see now

Comment: I don't see any update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your results are ordered by department, employee name, you could use the LAG function to find the first row for each department. You'd need to check each row to see if it has a different department than the previous row, something like this:

```
SELECT CASE /* Check if there's a different department number on this row compared to the previous row */
         WHEN NVL(LAG(t.dept) OVER (ORDER BY t.dept, t.emp_name),-1) <> t.dept /* If previous row is null (ie, this is the first row), use -1 as previous dept number so comparison does not fail */
         THEN t.dept
       END AS display_dept,
       t.emp_name,
       t.salary
FROM myTable t
ORDER BY t.dept, t.emp_name
```

That said, as others have pointed out, this really isn't something SQL is meant to do; you'd be much better off having this logic be in whatever is displaying the query results than in the query itself.